# ASP.NET MVC Service locator to inject dependencies into a web handler

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, dependency-injection, ninject

I used to have a standard ASP.NET MVC 3 application that was Ninject-wired via WebActivators preAppStart hook. My controllers were dependency injected via constructor injection - classic.

However not I need to handle some request via .ashx web handler. As know from several discussions here on SO, the only way to inject into a handler is via service locator instance.

What if I need to inject exactly an instance that was instanciated in Ninject kernel for  Controllers?

My `ISessionChecker` is bound to an `XmlSessionChecker` in Singleton scope in ninject module and the module is loaded into kernel and the kernel is in bootstraped into an ASP.NET MVC application at app_start.

Now I need my handlers to be locating this very same instance of XmlSessionChecker from global kernel. Can I somehow get this kernel as a service locator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it turns out I could just use `System.Web.Mvc.DependencyResolver.Current.GetService` to locate my dependency, as I would in any other MVC 3 app's code.

Comment: Thank you very much. You saved my day. I've been looking for a solution to this for hours. Till I found yours :)